# Meteor method call runs into infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, use-effect, use-state

I am new to Meteor and trying to fetch data from an API by passing different parameters from an array but it's running into an infinite loop. I can see the object is rendered again and again and the value keeps on changing instead of appending the correct value into the object after the response from the call.

```
let [projectvalue, setProjectvalue] = useState({});
let projectList = ['abc','def','bbb','sss'];


  projectList.map(projectName => {
    useEffect(
      (project = projectName) =>
        Meteor.call(
          'method.getValue',
          { project },
          (error, resp) => {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);
            resp.status.map(val => {
              if(val.key == "data"){
                setProjectvalue({...projectvalue, [projectName] : val.actualValue })
              }
            })
          }
        ),
    );
  });

console.log(projectvalue);
```

I need to get the actualValues from the response for different project names.

Edited:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    projectList.map(project => {
      Meteor.call(
        'method.getValue',
        { project },
        (error, resp) => {
          if (error) throw new Error(error);
          resp.status.map(val => {
             if(val.key == "data"){
              setProjectvalue({...projectvalue, [projectName] : val.actualValue })
           }
          })
        }
      )
    })
  }
  ,[projectList]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing dependency array for `useEffect` hook. And hooks should be placed on top level at function scope. Not inside `map` method:

```
useEffect(
  projectList.map(projectName => {
    Meteor.call(
      'method.getValue',
      { projectName },
      (error, resp) => {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        resp.status.map(val => {
          if(val.key == "data"){
            setProjectvalue({...projectvalue, [projectName] : val.actualValue })
          }
        })
      }
    )
  });
, []);
```

See  official React Docs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

Comment: Did the same but still the loop is running infinite and the object value changes everytime. Edited and added the code in the question

Comment: regarding dependencies it depeds on how you want to use that hook. If you will pass   empty array of dependencies it will run only once on mount. Passinng `projectList` will take nno effect as this is just an variable, not state or prop. If you will pass state value to dependecy `useEffect` will run every time state changes. See more info https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: I need to run only once and get all the values corresponding to that projectList array. I passed empty array in the dependencies but now the object has one value.

Comment: {abc: "72.43"}
{def: "58.76"}
{bbb: "65.54"}
{sss: "83.14"}

Comment: @XXDebugger replace `[projectName]` to `[project]` in your code

Comment: what value do you get? It's hard to say without more info.